# Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)

Tags: apt

I'm sorry in advance if I am leaving out critical information, or if I don't follow posting rules. I am pretty new to all this.

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.0.4 as a dual boot with windows 7.
I ran into a problem. Not sure what I did that caused it.
When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following errors:

```
...
Fetched 67.5 kB in 5s (12.2 kB/s)           
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: dl.google.com stable Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)
W: GPG error: us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)
W: GPG error: us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)
W: GPG error: us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)
W: GPG error: extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)

W: Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please let me know if there is other information that is needed. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue in two steps:

1. Installed debian-keyring (**sudo apt-get install debian-keyring**)
2. run apt-get update again and for each missing key run (**sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys** *XXXXXXXX*)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Open the software and updates app from the dash and choose the "other software tab".

Find the entry `security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release`

Un-check or delete this, then open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It should now work, you just have an invalid software repo installed.

Comment: I think I have a more serious problem. I can't even open the "software and updates" app

Comment: Please run: sudo apt-get install gpgv :and tell me if it is installed

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It's already installed. Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: OK Try removing and reinstalling gpgv: sudo apt-get purge gpgv : sudo apt-get install gpgv :run each command separately.

Comment: Uh so I ran the first command. Then when I tried running the second command it says "sudo: apt-get: command not found". Now I'm realllly screwed

Comment: You dont need the : after sudo just sudo apt-get install gpgv

Comment: I'm not that computer illiterate. Your command completely ruined my install. I'm going to do a fresh install later. I guess thanks for trying, but you really should know what your suggestions will do before posting it.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the command, if you just google the issue you will see this is a known fix.

Comment: No its not. I googled plenty before I asked here. There is no info specifically for this problem. Gpgv is obviously critical for the system, something that I was not aware of, and apparently you were not aware of either. Sudo apt-get purge works well, but only if it doesnt delete your ability to use apt-get!!

Comment: I was trying to avoid a full reinstall. Thanks for decending into rage. I appreciate your hatefulness.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. GPG errors with keys, added keys as above, issue still remained.

Backed up /etc/apt then replaced sources.list file with file seen here [github trusty default sources](https://gist.github.com/justbuchanan/d045498c95fa1cd2dc70)

Deleted trusted.gpg files. Restarted...

Now, GPG error "is gpgv installed?" (This error type does not show keys.)

Clicked "Software Updater" Settings, Authentication tab, **Restore Defaults**. GPGV working again, software updates working as well, had to manually add 1 key, now sudo apt-get update in terminal error free.